# Is it okay to say "I bought a dresser from a furniture shop"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-choice

In this case "**in**" is the correct preposition, but is it possible to say  "I bought a dresser *from* a furniture shop"? If yes, does it have the same meaning as "I bought a dresser *in* a furniture shop" ?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. You were in the shop when you made the purchase, but _buy something from a shop_ is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: **Buy from** emphasizes the shop originally owned the dresser. **Buy in** emphasizes where the speaker was when they bought it. If the purchase was online, only **from** would be appropriate.